# error to access dll file

Tags: excel, dll, vba

i have created the 64bit math1.dll on my machine using visual studio 2015 by using c programming. 
i copy that dll file into another machine and I try to access it through vba7 but it shows file not found error .

after that I tried the following command  into cmd :
`c:\windows\System32>%windir%\System32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\System32\math1.dll`

Then it shows following message box [error message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aToeJ.jpg)

[image]

My machine configuration :
Operating system :Windows 8.1
Processor :intel(R) core(TM)i5-4460 CPU @3.20 gHz

Another machine configuration
Operating system :Windows 8.1
Processor :intel(R) core(TM)i7-4600U CPU @2.10 GHz 2.70 GHz

My question is how can I access that math1.dll file into Microsoft excel office 2013 64bit in vba7?

Answer (score 1):

In this case most likely you are missing dependent DLL files, such as [Visual Studio 2015 C++ Redistributable x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

If that doesn't fix it check with dependency walker for missing referenced DLLs http://dependencywalker.com/

If that fails I would check using SysInternals `[ProcMon][2]` to confirm the processing attempting to open DLL is 64-bit, and also to look for any NAME NOT FOUDN, ACCESS DENIED, or SHARING VIOLATION errors related to the problem.

Comment: i downloaded the dependence dll after that also it shows the same error